# Updating Controls From Another Thread/Class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a beginner in WPF and I am working on a small personal project. I am wondering what is the best/proper way to achieve what I want. The setup is this: User clicks a `button` which will call a class named `ProcessManager`. `ProcessManager` will then set up a timer that will call another class named `DeviceController` that will write data to a database. What I want is a way for `DeviceController` to change a textbox on the GUI to let users know about any error encountered writing in the database.

The code below works, but after I extract the code inside `taskTimer.Elapsed += delegate{ }` to another method, it throws a `"cannot access this because it is owned by another thread"` error.

```
public void StartMonitoring()
{
    var mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().FirstOrDefault(x => x is MainWindow) as MainWindow;

    var _schedule = DateTime.Now;
    var _nextTaskSched = _schedule.AddSeconds(10);
    var _timerTicks = (_nextTaskSched - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
    var taskTimer = new Timer(_timerTicks);

    taskTimer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        //call DeviceController here//
        //do stuff//
        //something went wrong//
        mainWindow.txtError.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        { mainWindow.txtError.Text = "Something went wrong"; }));
    };
    taskTimer.Start();
}
```

Any help/suggestions/references is appreciated.

Comment: Post the method that actually raises the exception. Simply extracting the delegate to another method won't raise any exceptions.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos It actually does raise the exception I mentioned. If I do `taskTimer.Elapsed += delegate {NewMethod};` and put `mainWindow.txtError.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        { mainWindow.txtError.Text = "Something went wrong"; }));` inside `NewMethod` it will throw an error. @mm8 explained it below but I haven't tested it.

Comment: no, that doesn't explain the error at all. `.Dispatcher.Invoke` will marshal the call to the UI thread. You said you extracted the handler into another method. Post *that* code

Comment: In any case, trying to acces one form's controls from another form or thread is a bad idea. In WPF, it's a *very* bad idea - the stack was built to work through data binding, commands, messages, event aggregators, MVVM etc, not through direct UI manipulation. You can use `Progress<T>` and the `IProgress<T>` interface to publish events from one thread/module without hard-coding the reference to another. Various MVVM frameworks have explicit support for messages or event aggregators (aka subscribers)

Answer (score 2):

> The code below works, but after I extract the code inside `taskTimer.Elapsed += delegate{ }` to another method, it throws a "cannot access this because it is owned by another thread" error.

Use a [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) and handle its `Tick` event.

The difference is that the `Tick` event will be raised on the UI thread which is the only thread on which you can access UI controls. A `System.Timers.Timer`'s `Elapsed` event runs on a background thread.

Answer (score 1):

`.Dispatcher.Invoke` will dispatch the call to the UI thread. You shouldn't be getting that exception. You should post the refactored code instead.

In any case, the design isn't good as it adds a hard dependency between the monitoring thread and the UI. Forms and modules shouldn't have direct references to one another, especially in WPF.

WPF adds data binding, commands, messages so applications *don't* have to hard-code references between forms. What gets displayed on a textbox today could appear on a Status panel textbox the next week. You shouldn't have to modify business or service modules for such a minor UI change.

MVVM frameworks add explicit support for application/business events through messages or event aggregators. The actual names depend on the MVVM framework.

The .NET Runtime itsel provides the `IProgress<T>` interface and `Progress<T>` class to publish progress objects between threads. The `Progress<T>` class will raise an event or call a callback on the thread it was created each time someone calls `IProgress<T>`. This means you can just pass the interface around and the monitoring/worker code won't have to know how or what handles the progress event.

`StartMonitoring` could be simplified to this :

```
public void StartMonitoring(IProgress<string> progress)
{
    var _schedule = DateTime.Now;
    var _nextTaskSched = _schedule.AddSeconds(10);
    var _timerTicks = (_nextTaskSched - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
    var taskTimer = new Timer(_timerTicks);

    taskTimer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        //call DeviceController here//
        //do stuff//
        //something went wrong//
        progress.Report("Something went wrong";);
    };
    taskTimer.Start();
}
```

Or you could pass the interface in the monitoring class's constructor

```
public class MyMonitor
{
    IProgress<sring> _progress;

    public MyMonitor(IProgress<string> progress,...)
    {
        ....
        _progress=progress;
    }

    public void StartMonitoring(IProgress<string> progress)
    {
        ...
        taskTimer.Elapsed += delegate
        {
            //call DeviceController here//
            //do stuff//
            //something went wrong//
            _progress.Report("Something went wrong";);
        };
        taskTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

If the method is created on the main window, all you'd have to do is create a `Progress<T>` in advance and pass it to the method :

```
public class MainWindow :...
{
    Progress<string> _progress;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _progress=new Progress<string>(OnProgress);
    }

    private void OnProgress(string message)
    {
        txtError.Text = message; 
    }


    public void MethodThatStartsMonitoring()
    {
        //This could be passed in a constructor too.
        myMonitor.StartMonitoring(_progress);
    }

}
```

`IProgress<T>` can accept any object, not just a string. That, combined with data binding, means you could update *multiple* controls at the same time.

Instead of a string, you could use a `Status` class, eg :

```
public class Status
{
    public bool IsError{get;set;}
    public string Message {get;set;}

    public Status(bool isError,string message)
    {
        IsError=isError;
        Message=message;
    }
}
```

You can use that class with `IProgress<T>` :

```
public void StartMonitoring(IProgress<Status> progress)
{
    ...
    taskTimer.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        progress.Report(new Status(false,"Starting"));
        //call DeviceController here//
        //do stuff//
        //something went wrong//
        progress.Report(new Status(true,"Something went wrong"));
    };
    ...
}
```

And change the main form's code to this :

```
public class MainWindow:INotifyPropertyChanged,...
{
    Progress<Status> _progress;

    private Status _status=new Status();
    public Status Status
    {
        get=>_status;
        set 
        {
            __status=value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Status");
        }

    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _progress=new Progress<Status>(OnProgress);
        this.DataContext=this;
    }

    private void OnProgress(Status status)
    {
        Status=status;
    }
```

You can add bindings from multiple controls now to the `Status` property, either in XAML or in code eg :

```
    <TextBox x:Name="MyErrorBox" Text="{Binding Status.Message}"/>
```

Now the progress handler and even the code-behind don't need to know about the elements that will display the data.

You can bind other properties as well, eg visibility :

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
...

<TextBox x:Name="MyErrorBox" 
         Text="{Binding Status.Message}"
         Visibility="{Binding Path=Status.IsError, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter} }" />
```

The text box will now appear only for error messages

Comment: Thank you for this. The first version (using `string`) you've given works perfect. However, I am having trouble making the second version work (I want to use this approach, looks cleaner). Would you mind taking a look? I am having errors specifically on changing the MainWindow's code.